# the reuse of subclass of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, reusability

I'm trying to make a subclass of UITableViewCell, which simply contains a UILabel Property "nameLabel" and a UILabel Property "statusLabel".To dequeue the cells correctly, I implemented the **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** method like this:

PS: The text of statusLabel is from twitter API, so I have to send the size of it to **[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:]**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StatusCellView";
    StatusCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                        CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[StatusCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    for (UIView *subView in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if (![cell viewWithTag:kNameLabelTag]) {
        //init the nameLabel and [cell.contentView addsubview:nameLabel]
    }
    if (![cell viewWithTag:kStatusLabelTag]) {
        //init the statusLabel and [cell.contentView addsubview:statusLabel]
    }

    return cell;
```

As you can see, this works well when the data is not so large. But my question is :

- I think removing and adding the subview repeatedly will make the performance bad. It's a rude way...
- I can implement the same function without subclassing UITableViewCell. Is there any way to make use of the subclass?

Comment: Yes, there is one use of the subclass: you must be doing the cell setup in the subclass' initializer, and *not* in the table view's delegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why you have to remove them...this seems like a perfectly reasonable way of doing it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StatusCellView";
StatusCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                    CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[StatusCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //init the nameLabel and [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];
    //init the statusLabel and [cell.contentView addsubview:statusLabel]
}
else {
    UILabel *nameLabel = [cell viewithTag:kStatusLabelTag];
    nameLabel.frame = newFrame;
    nameLabel.text = newText
    //etc, etc, etc
}
return cell;
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried the way you give. Let me give you more code `cell.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect(10.0,2.0,300.0,statusTextSize.height)` and `CGSize statusTextSize = [self.unsureText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(150.0f, 1000.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap]` @borrrden

Comment: If use the code you gave, the reuse of the cell will be incorrect. When I scroll down the TableView and scroll back, the label is messy...

Comment: So, I remove and reinit them every time. But it seems not a good code.

Comment: Forgive me for my poor English, I mean, the content view of cells isn't in the correct frame. For example, when I scroll the table view, the title is on the position of subtitle's, which happens in the coming cell.

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually getting the views in the "else" section?  Did you forget to set the tags?  Are you passing in the same frame that you would have with init?  Your problem doesn't make sense to me...I use this exact method for my table view and have no problems so it must be that you are getting "nil" when you call `[cell ViewWithTag:]` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I took the frame for a readonly property at the beginning. It's my fault.